# Looking for suggestion on increasing performance when performing an ETL operation on a 100,000+ row Excel document (in C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, task-parallel-library

Let me preface this by saying, I know this would work far, far faster as an SSIS job but at this point it's become an academic exercise

I have an API (c#, dotnet core 2.2) that accepts a folder path as a string and then parses the excel documents (using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging and DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet) in that path and does a little processing and using Entity Framework, writes them to a MSSql database. My problem is that the file (a list of library users) is around 132,000 rows long and can take upwards of 60 minutes to process.

As you can see below, I have tried using Parallel ForEach to speed it up but where I can use it, it hasn't made too much difference. In the ExtractUserProfiles method, I was getting an exception stating that the process had tried to access a point before the beginning of the stream and in the provider class I was getting a context exception,I'm still not sure why it works one level lower (in the ProcessCells method).

This code works, I'm really just after any suggestions on how to improve it's efficiency (or anything else I've done wrong)

I have excluded the controller and my initial "handler" classes as they contain no real logic

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly ILibraryProvider _libraryProvider;
    private readonly INotificationHandler _notifyService;


    public ProfileService(ILibraryProvider libraryProvider, INotificationHandler notifyService)
    {
        _libraryProvider = libraryProvider;
        _notifyService = notifyService;
    }


    public async Task<IEnumerable<ILibraryProfile>> ProcessExcelStream(string libFile)
    {
        var userProfiles = new Dictionary<string, LibraryProfile>();
        var lib = File.OpenRead(libFile);
        try
        {
            using (var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(lib, false))
            {
                var workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
                var worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
                var rows = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>().ToList();

                //Dictionary to map row data into key value pair
                userProfiles = await ExtractUserProfiles(rows, workbookPart).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (OpenXmlPackageException ex)
        {
            await _notifyService.NotifyUsers("NoReply@email.com",
                $"Unable to open excel document:  {ex}",
                "Exception processing Library User Profile Event");
        }
        finally
        {
            lib.Close();
        }
        return IterateOutput(userProfiles);
    }      

    private async Task<Dictionary<string, LibraryProfile>> ExtractUserProfiles(List<Row> allRows, WorkbookPart workbookPart)
    {
        //Dictionary to map row data into key value pair
        var userProfiles = new Dictionary<string, LibraryProfile>();

        foreach (var currentRow in allRows) // HAVE TRIED USING PARALLEL FOREACH HERE BUT I GET AN ERROR FROM THE WORKBOOK. POINTER MOVED TO BEFORE BEGINNING OF STREAM
        {
            try
            {
                var currentLibraryUser = await ProcessCells(currentRow, workbookPart, new LibraryProfile()).ConfigureAwait(false);

                //Add productId and its respective data to dictionary
                if (!userProfiles.ContainsKey(currentRow.RowIndex) &&
                       (
                           !string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentLibraryUser.UserLastName) &&
                           !string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentLibraryUser.UserBarcode) &&
                           !string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentLibraryUser.UserFirstName)
                       )
                 )
                    userProfiles.Add(currentRow.RowIndex, currentLibraryUser);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await _notifyService.NotifyUsers("NoReply@email.com",
                    $"Unable to open excel document:  {ex}",
                    "Exception processing Library User Profile Event");
            }
        }

        return userProfiles;
    }

    private async Task<LibraryProfile> ProcessCells(Row currentRow,
        WorkbookPart workbookPart, LibraryProfile currentLibraryUser)
    {
        try
        {

            var phoneType = string.Empty;
    //No idea why the parallel foreach works here but not one level up
            Parallel.ForEach(currentRow.Elements<Cell>(), c =>
            {
                if (c.DataType != null && c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
                {
                    var stringId = Convert.ToInt32(c.InnerText);
                    var val = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>()
                        .ElementAt(stringId).InnerText;
                    //Find cell index and map each cell and add in key value pair
                    switch (GetColumnIndex(c.CellReference))
                    {
                        case 0:
                            currentLibraryUser.UserProfile = "TG_DEBTCOLL";
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            currentLibraryUser.UserBarcode = val;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            currentLibraryUser.UserLastName = val;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            currentLibraryUser.UserFirstName = val;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            currentLibraryUser.UserAddressEmail = val;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            switch (val.ToLower())
                            {
                                case "mobile phone":
                                    phoneType = "mobile";
                                    break;
                                case "phone":
                                    phoneType = "phone";
                                    break;
                                case "work phone":
                                    phoneType = "work phone";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    phoneType = string.Empty;
                                    break;
                            }

                            break;
                        case 7:
                            switch (phoneType)
                            {
                                case "mobile":
                                    currentLibraryUser.UserMobileNumber = val;
                                    break;
                                case "phone":
                                    currentLibraryUser.UserPhoneNumber = val;
                                    break;
                                case "work":
                                    currentLibraryUser.UserWorkNumber = val;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }

                            break;
                    }

                }
            });
            return currentLibraryUser;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await _notifyService.NotifyUsers("NoReply@email.com",
                $"Unable to open excel document:  {ex}",
                "Exception processing Library User Profile Event");
        }

        return null;
    }

    private int? GetColumnIndex(string cellReference)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellReference))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var columnReference = Regex.Replace(cellReference.ToUpper(), @"[\d]", string.Empty);

        var columnNumber = -1;
        var multiplier = 1;

        foreach (var c in columnReference.ToCharArray().Reverse())
        {
            columnNumber += multiplier * ((int)c - 64);
            multiplier *= 26;
        }

        return columnNumber;// + 1;
    }

    private IEnumerable<ILibraryProfile> IterateOutput(Dictionary<string, LibraryProfile> userProfiles)
    {
        return userProfiles.Select(exportRow => exportRow.Value)
            .Select(profile => new LibraryProfile()
            {
                UserBarcode = profile.UserBarcode,
                UserLastName = profile.UserLastName,
                UserFirstName = profile.UserFirstName,
                UserAddressEmail = profile.UserAddressEmail,
                UserMobileNumber = profile.UserMobileNumber,
                UserWorkNumber = profile.UserWorkNumber,
                UserPhoneNumber = profile.UserPhoneNumber,
                UserProfile = profile.UserProfile,
            })
            .ToList();
    }

public async Task<string> AddOrUpdateUserProfile(IEnumerable<ILibraryProfile> userProfiles)
    {
        await _libraryProvider.InsertOrUpdateLibraryUser(userProfiles).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return string.Empty;

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _libraryProvider?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

and then my provider

```
public class LibraryProvider : ILibraryProvider
{
    internal EvoqContext LibContext;
    private readonly INotificationHandler NotifyService;

    public LibraryProvider(EvoqContext context, INotificationHandler notifyService)
    {
        LibContext = context;
        NotifyService = notifyService;
    }

    public async Task InsertOrUpdateLibraryUser(IEnumerable<ILibraryProfile> tcLibraryUsers)
    {
        try
        {
            var libUsers = LibContext.TcLibraryUser.Select(x => x);
            var rowCount = 0;

            foreach (var tcLibraryUser in tcLibraryUsers)
            //Parallel.ForEach(tcLibraryUsers, async tcLibraryUser => causes an exception due to the context being modified
            {
                if (tcLibraryUser.UserBarcode == null) throw new NoNullAllowedException("Barcode");
                var libUser = libUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Barcode == tcLibraryUser.UserBarcode
                                                           && x.FirstName ==
                                                           tcLibraryUser.UserFirstName
                                                           && x.LastName ==
                                                           tcLibraryUser.UserLastName);
                if (libUser == null)
                {
                    libUser = new TcLibraryUser()
                    {
                        Barcode = tcLibraryUser.UserBarcode,
                        LastName = tcLibraryUser.UserLastName,
                        FirstName = tcLibraryUser.UserFirstName,
                        EmailAddress = tcLibraryUser.UserAddressEmail,
                        ProfileValue = tcLibraryUser.UserProfile,
                        PhoneNumber = tcLibraryUser.UserPhoneNumber,
                        MobilePhone = tcLibraryUser.UserMobileNumber,
                        WorkPhone = tcLibraryUser.UserWorkNumber,
                    };
                    LibContext.TcLibraryUser.Add(libUser);
                }
                else
                {
                    libUser.EmailAddress = tcLibraryUser.UserAddressEmail;
                    libUser.PhoneNumber = tcLibraryUser.UserPhoneNumber;
                    libUser.WorkPhone = tcLibraryUser.UserWorkNumber;
                    libUser.MobilePhone = tcLibraryUser.UserMobileNumber;
                    libUser.ProfileValue = tcLibraryUser.UserProfile;
                    LibContext.TcLibraryUser.Update(libUser);
                }

                rowCount++; // Purely for debugging, to gauge progress
            }

            await LibContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await NotifyService.NotifyUsers("NoReply@email.com",
                $"Exception writing library data to database:  {ex}",
                "Exception processing Library User Profile Event");
        }
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        LibContext?.Dispose();
        NotifyService?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

Out of interest LibraryProfile looks like

```
public class LibraryProfile
{
    public string UserProfile { get; set; }
    public string UserBarcode { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserAddressEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserPhoneNumber { get; set; } 
    public string UserWorkNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserMobileNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion 1. not store 130000 lines of data in an excel file

Comment: Also you might get more luck out of access the document through OLEDB provider, and using builk insert to SQL server

Comment: I know you are primarily interested in optimising what you have.... but I suggest an alternative approach of bulk loading the file into the database and using `UPDATE` statements to apply transformations.

Comment: Most likely the culprit is the `libUsers.FirstOrDefault(…)` call - a database query per each row. What is the primary/unique key of `TcLibraryUser`?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion 1: Using ADO.Net directly instead of Entity Framework. This bypasses ORM logic and is significantly faster.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/

Suggestion 2: I would recommend using EPPlus library instead of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging and DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet
This is faster and more natural to use.

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go